# Prototype Element.update() function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

Using Element.update() prototype function:

```
[ ... ]
var link_1 = new Element('a').update( '<'  );
var link_2 = new Element('a').update( '<<' );
[ ... ]
```

Only in IE i'm getting:

```
'link_1' is not defined
```

How can i write the string "<" into a prototype element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the HTML entities of those characters instead of the actual characters as they are typically the start of HTML tags.

So instead of `update("<")` try doing `update("&lt;")`

And `update("&lt;&lt;")`

[List of entity replacements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)